# How to convert an SQLCOMMAND to INT

Tags: html, asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have the following code where table name is student and column name is `sem_of_study` from the type of `INT`

```
Dim userquery As String = "select sem_of_study from student where username='" + Session("user") + "'"
Dim usercom As New SqlCommand(userquery, conn)
Dim a = usercom.ExecuteReader
```

I was wondering if I could convert the SQL Command into integer so I can use it in `IF` statements!!

so that variable a would

```
if a=1 then 

else if a=2 then
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact you should use `parameterized queries` (search SO -- plenty of examples), you need to do something like this reading in the `DataReader` rows:

```
Dim a as Integer
Dim myReader As SqlDataReader = usercom.ExecuteReader()

If myReader.HasRows Then
  myReader.Read()
  a = myReader.GetInt32(0)
End If
```

And for the parameters:

```
Dim userquery As String = "select sem_of_study from student where username=@username"
Dim usercom as SqlCommand = new SqlCommand()
usercom.Connection = conn
usercom.CommandType = CommandType.Text
usercom.CommendText = userquery 
usercom.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", Session("user"))
```